# How to convert string to char, C

Tags: c, string, char, converters

Output this code is: `\123`. I want only S, but I want to use my char a,b,c,d. My question is: There are converter string to char?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){

char stir[4];
char a = '\\';
char b = '1';
char c = '2';
char d = '3';

stir[0] = a;
stir[1] = b;
stir[2] = c;
stir[3] = d;

printf("%s",stir);

return 0;
}
```

Comment: The last character in the array should be 0. (Not '0' but just 0.) This will probably be closed as a duplicate....

Comment: @Brick: The last character in the array should be `'\0'`, that is the NUL character. Just 0 is an integer, not a character (although the compiler will silently treat that as `'\0'`).

Comment: It's certainly possible to write code to convert the characters that make up an octal constant into the corresponding character — I've got one such kicking around my library.  It's neither dreadfully hard nor completely trivial, mainly because of the complexities of the rules, and dealing with other options such as `\x53` or escapes like `'\\'`, etc.

Comment: @Striezel type of `'\0'` is `int`.

Comment: Far too common mistake, no `'\0'` terminator. Someone should know where the duplicate can be ... Oh, and what is your question?

Comment: @BLUEPIXY: But `'\0'` is a `char` literal. How can its type be `int`?

Comment: @Striezel see **6.4.4.4 Character constants p10** of  [n1570.pdf](https://docs.google.com/viewer?url=www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf&pli=1)